# Combinação de vários itens

Tags: c++, matemática, combinações

Eu tenho um conjunto de itens e cada item possui os seguintes elementos:

```
E = (índice, espessura, largura, demanda)
i = índice; e = espessura; l = largura; d = demanda;
```

Tenho ainda mais duas variáveis:

```
int min, max;
```

Chamemos as combinações possíveis de `C`, que `C` é o conjunto dos `i` de `E`, tal que `soma(l(C))` seja menor que o `max` e maior que o `min`. `i` pode repetir no conjunto.

Por exemplo, tenho os seguintes itens:

```
E = {{1, 2, 50, 100}, {2, 2, 30, 100}, {3, 2, 40, 100};
min = 100; max = 200;
```

Então

```
C = {
    {1,1}, // Sum(l(C)) = 100
    {1,1,1}, // Sum(l(C)) = 150
    {1,1,2,3}, // Sum(l(C)) = 170
    {1,1,3,1}, // Sum(l(C)) = 190
    // e mais algumas várias outras possibilidades
}
```

Porém, `C` não é um conjunto de par ordenados, então `{1,2} = {2,1}`.

Como vou fazer para calcular todas essas possibilidades sem que haja repetições idênticas como essa?